# [Rails]Page caching on deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, nginx, capistrano

I've actually a problem with my deployed rails 3 app. It is hosted on a linux server using Nginx. But I have a problem. 
When I update my app with Capistrano and I reload the page in my browser, the page is still on the website's previous version. That until I reload the page deleting the cache with "CTRL + R". Or if I directly enter the IP adress of my server I don't have any problem. Is it a DNS problem ? 
Thank you.

Comment: If you inspect the page headers being returned by your page, do you see an entry for ````Cache-Control```` that has a value of anything other than ````Cache-Control:max-age=0````?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, I don't see any Cache-Control entry. Should I set something ?